# Is auto-publish for Experience Manager configurable?

Tags: publishing, experience-manager

I notice that when session preview is enabled for Experience Manager, my page is auto-published to my staging website when I click *Finish Editing*. When I disable session preview, it no longer auto publishes. Is it possible to configure this behaviour somewhere (for example if I do not want to auto-publish when using session preview, or do wish to auto-publish when not using session preview)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no configuration for that.

However, the behavior is unrelated to Session Preview -- it will always attempt to Publish the item after it has been saved successfully. I'm not sure what scenario you are describing where it doesn't Publish - but maybe it was because there were no changes to save?

Comment: Thanks Peter - I am definately making changes, and its strange as I now tried some other pages, and they do auto-publish, but for some reason this one does not.

Comment: Maybe the item is put into the Publish Queue but it doesn't make it out of there? Maybe no items are resolved?

Comment: Actually I take back my previous comment about some pages being OK - it was the event system doing the autopublish - I have disabled this and now they do not publish either. There is nothing in the queue either.. Can it be a blueprint context issue? I have a BP hierarchy with Content at the top (where the component is created/edited), then Website master (where the page is created/edited), then the website itself (where the page is published). Checking the context settings it looks to be set up OK though...

Comment: I could be related to the context, yeah. Try calling $display.getView().getPublicationId() -- that's the Publication it will try to publish the item in.